# sed, Prints all rows that contain 3 or more consecutive characters Are identical

Tags: sed

Prints all rows that contain 3 or more consecutive characters Are identical.

from this:

```
abc2 1ababab
dea 13333
12112112
abc cd aabbcc
adddb
aa bb ccccccc11
hhh
```

to this:

```
dea 13333
adddb
aa bb ccccccc11
hhh
```

"3" is 4 times,
"d" is 3..and..so.

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Simply with **`grep`**:

```
grep -E '(.)\1\1' file
```

The output:

```
dea 13333
adddb
aa bb ccccccc11
hhh
```

---

Or the same with **`sed`**:

```
sed -E '/(.)\1\1/!d' file
```

---

- `-E` - extended regular expressions used in both approaches